# find a limit functions $g_n(x) = \sqrt[n]{x^n + \tan^n x}

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$g_n(x) = \sqrt[n]{x^n + \tan^n x},\; x\in \left[0, \frac \pi 2\right) $$
Well, tried to find this limit with the help of standard method, but failed and now I have no idea

Comment: In those places where $|x|>|\tan(x)|$ you can write $g_n(x)=|x|\sqrt[n]{1+(\tan(x)/x)^n}$. In those where $|x|\leq|\tan(x)|$ do $g_n(x)=|\tan(x)|\sqrt[n]{(x/\tan(x))^n+1}$. In both cases, the radical that results tends to $1$.

Answer (score 3):

On $[0,\pi/2 )$ we have $x \leq \tan x$. Hence $\tan x \leq g_n(x) \leq 2^{1/n} \tan x$. Hence $g _n(x) \to \tan x$ as $n \to \infty$. To prove the inequality $x \leq \tan x$ for $x \in [0,\pi/2 )$ note that the derivative of $\tan x -x$ is positive, so this function is increasing. Since it vanishes when $x=0$ we get $x \leq \tan x$.